# SQL convert INT to datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, int

I have 1323648000 which is int(10). I need to be able to convert it to a date format of some sort. Something like dd/hh/yy hh:mm:ss. I have tried to us a few examples on here but i cannot seem to get it to work.  I have tried to cast it as a varchar(10) and convert but nothing. Excel also outputs ########. Is the number incorrect then?

```
SELECT
engine4_openid_statusstats.openidstat_id,
CONVERT(datetime,CAST(engine4_openid_statusstats.openidstat_time AS varchar(10),3),
engine4_openid_services.openidservice_id,
engine4_openid_services.openidservice_name
FROM
engine4_openid_statusstats ,
engine4_openid_services
```

Comment: What RDBMS? Looks like MS SQL Server...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's looking like an Unix-style epoch-based timestamp, i.e. number of seconds since 1970.

The conversion is RDBMS-specific. With SQLITE you'd do

```
select datetime( 1323648000, 'unixepoch' );
```

and that yields 2011-12-12 00:00:00 (GMT).

Check your RDBMS documentation for date-time conversion functions.

Comment: You were correct. It was a unix timestamp. I used 'FROM UNIXTIME(engine4_openid_statusstats.openidstat_time)' and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If that is indeed being stored as Epoch Time (which it looks like it is), those are the number of seconds since January 01, 1970.  You can convert it to a datetime by adding the seconds to this date.

```
SELECT DATEADD(SS, 1323648000, '01/01/1970')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TO_CHAR(column_name, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss')
```

Comment: didnt work :( SELECT
engine4_openid_statusstats.openidstat_id,
TO_CHAR(CAST(engine4_openid_statusstats.openidstat_time AS varchar(10),3), 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss'),
engine4_openid_services.openidservice_id,
engine4_openid_services.openidservice_name
FROM
engine4_openid_statusstats ,
engine4_openid_services